# c# get and set methods vs. method overload: Which is better?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I can do like:

```
{
    void SetAnything(para, para, para) {...}
    int GetAnything(para, para) {...}
}
```

.. or I can do like:

```
{
    int Anything(para, para, para) {...}
    int Anything(para, para) {...}
}
```

I have to decide which way I go, so I ask you:

**What is the prefered way between these both approaches and why?**

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the replies so far. Since there was not fully clear, what my method(s) are doing, I rewrote the examples a little bit:

```
{
    void SetBudget(department, year, decimal value) {...}
    decimal GetBudget(department, year) {...}
}
```

.. or I can do like:

```
{
    decimal Budget(department, year, decimal value) {...}
    decimal Budget(department, year) {...}
}
```

.. or even:

```
{
    void Budget(department, year, decimal value) {...}
    decimal Budget(department, year) {...}
}
```

Still preferred with Set/Get prefix?

Comment: You have something called properties in C# for getters and setters...

Comment: How does the method that takes 3 parameters return an `int` in the second code snippet? It is void in the first code snippet.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn No, properties don't have parameters.

Comment: @Sweeper Well, in setter you have `value`, in getter - why would you need parameter... I think I don't understand question fully :)

Answer (score 1):

That is not overloading in a way anyone would expect. You're clearly doing two different things (setting and getting).

**Post Edit**

---

Still, the fact remains the "overloads" are actually accomplishing two separate goals; one is setting and one is getting. That wouldn't be an issue if you're using the given construct for this; properties. But since you're actually overloading a method, it's not typical.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the first approach is correct and the second is **discouraged**.

If you are looking for a way to define custom getters and setters, the naming should be:

```
Get[variable name]
Set[variable name]
```

so you now by name, what you are doing and it is way easier for you and others to see clearly what the code is doing.

Overloading one method for totally different purposes leads to messy code, where you are invoking one method (but overloaded versions) for totally different purposes. And in a code, how would you decide which overload to use? Just by number of parameters? Sounds like a nightmare to me...